# Send password as char array to rest template

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am using spring3.0. I want tp read the password from properties file as char array and send it to the RestTemplate as char array. Is there a way I can do this. Currently with string it works fine. When I change it to char array authorization fails

I want to know the right way to handle this password reading and sending it to the respective webservice. The password I am referring to is already encrypted.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If its already encrypted why can't it be in String itself ?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? Do you need the password to authenticate with the webservice provider, i.e. do you want to call the webservice? What authentication method is used and what exactly are you doing? And _why_ can't you just use a string instead if that's working?

Comment: Fine, how did you handled the char array. Did you use "password."toCharArray() to convert it into char array and new String(charArray) ? What error did you get, a stack trace would help ?

Comment: The webservice is https. I need to send username and pwd for auth. I am trying to get the bean property as a char[]. So the setter is setPwd(char[] password) and getPassword return char[]. I send this value in the HttpHeaders of restTemplate by making this char[] as toString(). This is a static analysis finding and I am trying to correct it

Comment: @user1999099 Update/improve your question with the feedback given here. Don't try to answer all these questions here, because it makes it hard to follow.

Comment: What do you mean by "it fails". Elaborate on this. Did it not compile? Did it failed to deploy? Did it fail at runtime? Do you get any exceptions?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Basically Spring can read the password as a char array and do not try to do toString or String concatenation. Just use the StringBuilder or StringBuffer and append the character array to whatever is your need. This will handle the password correctly and it worked for me.

Comment: Can you post a code example of how to read the password as char array from the properties file?  I see that was asked in the question but I see how you did it in your answer.